# Not able to print the cursor in the following block of code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, arrow-functions

I am trying to console.log the cursor. But it does not return anything. Why does cursor not print, When it has been defined outside the query.forEach(). Shouldn't changes to value of balanceList inside the iteration be maintained?

```
import * as mongodb from 'mongodb';
const MongoClient = mongodb.default.MongoClient;
import genSegWallet from './utils/genSegWallet.js';

const uri =
    'mongodb+srv://dragonfly:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.5fsiovo.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
const client = new MongoClient(uri);

async function getAddrs() {
    const query = await client.db('users').collection('userAddress').find().toArray()
    let cursor = {}
    query.forEach(async (entry) => {
        const username = await entry['username'];
        const mnemonic = await entry['address']['mnemonic']
        const address = await genSegWallet(mnemonic)
        const addressArr = Object.values(address)
        cursor[username] = {}
        addressArr.forEach(async (addr, index) => {
            // const bal = await getBal(addr);
            const bal = 0;
            cursor[username][index] = { 'address': addr, 'balance': bal }
        })
    console.log(cursor) //Prints
    })
    console.log(cursor) //Does not print
    return cursor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function passed to forEach is async, so the forEach doesn't wait for completion of one before moving on.

The values inside the async function are awaited, so the console.log that is also inside it not executed until the data is availble.

The console.log outside the forEach is executed as soon as a promise is created for each element in the array, which is well before the data has resolved in order to set the cursor value.

You might try using `query.map` instead of forEach, so you get an array of the promises of executing the anonymous async function on each array element, and you can call `Promise.all` on that array to await them all at once.